# Making an index of sources quoted

Tags: indexing

I am working on my PhD Thesis, and need to create an index of all primary sources quoted.
I have created "cite" commands so that it automatically adds an index line whenever I cite:

```
\newcommand{\citeherm}[1]{\emph{Shepherd of Hermas}~#1\index{Shepherd of Hermas!#1}}
```

This works great, except that the index orders numerals incorrectly. '11' will come between '1' and '2', which is clearly incorrect in this case.

I have attached a minimal example. Who can help?

(BTW I have thought that you could do this by hand by using a running zero that does not print, but I wouldn't know how to automate that, in my command above.

```
\index{Shepherd of Hermas!03.13–18@3.13–8}
```

)

**Minimal example**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\newcommand{\citeherm}[1]{\emph{Shepherd of Hermas}~#1\index{Shepherd of Hermas!#1}}
\newcommand{\citeash}[1]{\emph{Testament of Asher}~#1\index{Testament of Asher!#1}}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

“bla bla bla” \citeherm{12.1}
“bla bla bla” \citeherm{12.2}
“bla bla bla” \citeherm{12.3}
“bla bla bla” \citeherm{12.4}
“bla bla bla” \citeherm{12.10}
“bla bla bla” \citeherm{12.11}
“bla bla bla” \citeherm{12.20}
“bla bla bla” \citeherm{12.21}


“bla bla bla” \citeash{1.1}
“bla bla bla” \citeash{2.1}
“bla bla bla” \citeash{10.1}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `\index{order@text}` where order determines the order and text the text to display. This way you could either use an additional counter, if you want them sorted in the order of appearance, or add a `0` in front without it being printed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that your references have the form `x.y-z`, possibly omitting the `-z` part, where `x`, `y`, and `z` are numbers less than 100:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\makeatletter
\def\bruin@normalize#1{\@bruin@normalizei#1-\@nil}
\def\@bruin@normalizei#1.#2-#3\@nil{%
    \two@digits{#1}.\two@digits{#2}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else
     -\expandafter\two@digits\expandafter{\@gobblehyphen#3}%
  \fi}
\def\@gobblehyphen#1-{#1}
\newcommand{\defcite}[2]{%
  \newcommand{#1}[1]{\emph{#2}~##1\index{#2!\bruin@normalize{##1}@##1}}%
}
\makeatother

\defcite{\citeherm}{Shepherd of Hermas}
\defcite{\citeash}{Testament of Asher}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

bla bla bla \citeherm{12.1}
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.2}
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.3}
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.4}
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.10}
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.11}
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.20}
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.21}


bla bla bla \citeash{1.1}
bla bla bla \citeash{2.1}
bla bla bla \citeash{10.1}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

If the format is different, then some corrections have to be made. For example, if the numbers can be three digits long, add

```
\def\three@digits#1{\ifnum#1<1000 0\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\fi#1}
```

and use `\three@digits` instead of `\two@digits`.

I've also defined a "catch-all" command for defining uniformly the indexing commands.

## Added: support for list arguments (and three digits)

```
\makeatletter
\def\three@digits#1{\ifnum#1<100 0\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\fi#1}
\def\bruin@normalize#1{\@bruin@normalizei#1-\@nil}
\def\@bruin@normalizei#1.#2-#3\@nil{%
    \three@digits{#1}.\three@digits{#2}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else
     -\expandafter\three@digits\expandafter{\@gobblehyphen#3}%
  \fi}
\def\@gobblehyphen#1-{#1}
\newcommand{\defcite}[2]{%
  \newcommand{#1}[1]{\emph{#2}\bruin@dolist{#2}{##1}}}
\def\bruin@dolist#1#2{%
  \toks@={~\@gobbletwo}%
  \@for\next:=#2\do{%
    \edef\next{,\noexpand\space\next
      \noexpand\index{#1!\expandafter\bruin@normalize\expandafter{\next}@\next}}%
    \toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\next}%
  }\the\toks@
}
\makeatother

\defcite{\citeherm}{Shepherd of Hermas}
\defcite{\citeash}{Testament of Asher}
```

Now an input such as `\citeherm{12.1,35.4,28.2}` will print

> Shepherd of Hermas 12.1, 35.4, 28.2

with a nonbreaking space between "Hermas" and the first number; it will index all three references.

## Added: support for chapter ranges

```
\makeatletter
\def\three@digits#1{\ifnum#1<100 0\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\fi#1}
\def\bruin@normalize#1{\@bruin@normalizei#1-.\@nil}
\def\@bruin@normalizei#1.#2-#3.#4\@nil{%
    \three@digits{#1}.\three@digits{#2}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax
     % same chapter range
     \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
       % simple range
       % already set
     \else
       -\expandafter\three@digits\expandafter{\@gobblehyphen#3}%
     \fi
  \else
     % different chapters range
     -\three@digits{#3}.\expandafter\three@digits\expandafter{\@gobblehyphenperiod#4}%
  \fi}
\def\@gobblehyphen#1-{#1}
\def\@gobblehyphenperiod#1-.{#1}

\newcommand{\defcite}[2]{%
  \newcommand{#1}[1]{\emph{#2}\bruin@dolist{#2}{##1}}}
\def\bruin@dolist#1#2{%
  \toks@={~\@gobbletwo}%
  \@for\next:=#2\do{%
    \edef\next{,\noexpand\space\next
      \noexpand\index{#1!\expandafter\bruin@normalize\expandafter{\next}@\next}}%
    \toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\next}%
  }\showthe\toks@\the\toks@
}
\makeatother

\defcite{\citeherm}{Shepherd of Hermas}
\defcite{\citeash}{Testament of Asher}
```

Now also `\citeherm{1.2-3.4}` will be indexed. Lists will continue to work as before.

## Added: support also for simple citations

```
\makeatletter
\def\three@digits#1{\ifnum#1<100 0\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\fi#1}
\def\bruin@normalize#1{\@bruin@normalizei#1.\@nil}
\def\@bruin@normalizei#1.#2\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
     % only one number
     \three@digits{#1}\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
     \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi{\@bruin@gobbleperiod#1.#2\@nil}
}
\def\@bruin@gobbleperiod#1.\@nil{\@bruin@normalizeii#1-.\@nil}
\def\@bruin@normalizeii#1.#2-#3.#4\@nil{%
    \three@digits{#1}.\three@digits{#2}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax
     % same chapter range
     \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
       % simple range
       % already set
     \else
       -\expandafter\three@digits\expandafter{\@gobblehyphen#3}%
     \fi
  \else
     % different chapters range
     -\three@digits{#3}.\expandafter\three@digits\expandafter{\@gobblehyphenperiod#4}%
  \fi}
\def\@gobblehyphen#1-{#1}
\def\@gobblehyphenperiod#1-.{#1}

\newcommand{\defcite}[2]{%
  \newcommand{#1}[1]{\emph{#2}\bruin@dolist{#2}{##1}}}
\def\bruin@dolist#1#2{%
  \toks@={~\@gobbletwo}%
  \@for\next:=#2\do{%
    \edef\next{,\noexpand\space\next
      \noexpand\index{#1!\expandafter\bruin@normalize\expandafter{\next}@\next}}%
    \toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\next}%
  }\the\toks@
}

\makeatother

\defcite{\citeherm}{Shepherd of Hermas}
\defcite{\citeash}{Testament of Asher}
```

This should allow also citations like `\citeherm{12}`.

## Final (?) addition

Here is a "LaTeX3" implementation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_bruin_argi_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bruin_argii_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bruin_argx_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bruin_temp_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bruin_final_tl

% First of all we split the comma separated list; we store |#1|, the
% title of the book, in |\bruin_argi_tl| and |\bruin_argx_tl| to
% contain |\use_none:nn| that at the end will gobble the first two
% tokens (a comma and a space); then we put the split list of
% arguments followed by |{\NoValue}| after |\bruin_process:n|, because
% it will be used to terminate the recursion.
\NewDocumentCommand\bruin_dolist:nn {m >{\SplitList{,}}m}{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_bruin_argi_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_bruin_argx_tl { \use_none:nn }
  \bruin_process:n #2 {\NoValue}
}
% |\bruin_process:n| initiates the recursion; it examines the contents
% of the first pair of braces after it and, if different from
% |\NoValue|, stores it into |\bruin_argii_tl|. Then it appends also
% it to the list |\bruin_argx_tl|, after a comma and a space. The same
% contents is also processed by |\bruin_normalize:n|. Then we execute
% |\bruin_do:| and call again |\bruin_process:n| to restart the recursion.
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_process:n {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {}% end of recursion
    {
     \tl_set:Nn \l_bruin_argii_tl {#1}
     \tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_argx_tl { \l_bruin_argx_tl , \c_space_tl #1 }
     \bruin_normalize:n {#1} \bruin_do: \bruin_process:n
    }
}
% |\bruin_normalize:n| is responsible for splitting an entry of the
% form |A-B| (|A| and |B| will actually be something like |1.2|) into
% the two components, which are passed to |\bruin_normalizei:nn|
\NewDocumentCommand\bruin_normalize:n {>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}m}{
  \bruin_normalizei:nn #1
}
% If the entry was |A-B|, |\bruin_normalizei:nn| is passed |{A}{B}|,
% otherwise it is passed |{A}{\NoValue}|
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_normalizei:nn {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\bruin_three:n {#1}} % simple entry
    {\bruin_three:nn {#1}{#2}} % complex entry
}
% |\bruin_three:n| splits an argument of the form |1.2.3| into the
% components; it's quite similar to |\bruin_normalize:n|
\NewDocumentCommand\bruin_three:n {>{\SplitArgument{2}{.}}m}{
  \bruin_threedo:nnn #1
  \tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_final_tl {\l_bruin_temp_tl}
}
% |\bruin_threedo:nnn| sets |\l_bruin_final_tl| to the components but
% with three digits; |1| is transformed into |001| and |1.2| becomes
% |001.002|, while |1.2.3| becomes |001.002.003|
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_threedo:nnn {
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_temp_tl
          {\bruin_threedig:n{#1}}}
       {\tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_temp_tl
          {\bruin_threedig:n{#1}.\bruin_threedig:n{#2}}}
    }
    {\tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_temp_tl
       {\bruin_threedig:n{#1}.\bruin_threedig:n{#2}.\bruin_threedig:n{#3}}
    }
}
% we do similarly for |\bruin_three:nn|, calling |\bruin_threedo:nnn| twice.
\NewDocumentCommand\bruin_three:nn
  {>{\SplitArgument{2}{.}}m >{\SplitArgument{2}{.}}m}
  { \bruin_threedo:nnn #1
    \tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_final_tl {\l_bruin_temp_tl }
    \bruin_threedo:nnn #2
    \tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_final_tl {\l_bruin_final_tl -- \l_bruin_temp_tl}
  }

\cs_new:Nn \bruin_do: {
  \cs_set:Nx \bruin_next: {
    \exp_not:N \index 
      {\l_bruin_argi_tl ! \l_bruin_final_tl \c_space_tl @ \l_bruin_argii_tl }
  }
  \bruin_next: 
}
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_threedig:n {
  \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {100}
    { 0 \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {10} {0}{} }
    {} #1
}

% |\bruin_defcite:nn| defines |#1| as a macro with one argument, first
% storing its second argument in it. So
%
% |\defcite{\citeT}{Title}|
%
% defines |\citeT| as if it were
%
% |\def\citeT#1{\emph{Title}\space\bruin_dolist:nn{Title}{#1}\l_bruin_argx_tl}|
%
% The token list |\l_bruin_argx_tl| will be built by |\bruin_dolist:nn|
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_defcite:nn {
  \cs_new:Npn #1##1{\emph{#2}\space\bruin_dolist:nn {#2}{##1} \l_bruin_argx_tl }}
\cs_set_eq:NN \defcite \bruin_defcite:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defcite{\citeherm}{Shepherd of Hermas}
\defcite{\citeash}{Testament of Asher}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

%\tracingmacros=1
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.1-2}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.2,13.9}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.3-13.4}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.10}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.11}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.20}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.21}
\newpage


bla bla bla \citeash{1.2.3}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeash{2.1}.
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeash{10.1,1.1,2.9-19}.
\newpage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

This should support also three levels, as you see in the `\citeash` example.

---

### Version after the July 2012 update of LaTeX3

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_bruin_argi_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bruin_argii_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bruin_argx_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bruin_temp_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bruin_final_tl

% First of all we split the comma separated list; we store |#1|, the
% title of the book, in |\bruin_argi_tl| and |\bruin_argx_tl| to
% contain |\use_none:nn| that at the end will gobble the first two
% tokens (a comma and a space); then we put the split list of
% arguments followed by |{\NoValue}| after |\bruin_process:n|, because
% it will be used to terminate the recursion.
\NewDocumentCommand\bruin_dolist:nn {m >{\SplitList{,}}m}{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_bruin_argi_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_bruin_argx_tl { \use_none:nn }
  \ProcessList{#2}{\bruin_process:n}
}
% |\bruin_process:n| does the recursion via \ProcessList; it
% stores its argument into |\bruin_argii_tl|. Then it appends also
% it to the list |\bruin_argx_tl|, after a comma and a space. The same
% contents is also processed by |\bruin_normalize:n|. Then we execute
% |\bruin_do:|.
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_process:n {
     \tl_set:Nn \l_bruin_argii_tl {#1}
     \tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_argx_tl { \l_bruin_argx_tl , \c_space_tl #1 }
     \bruin_normalize:n {#1} \bruin_do: 
}
% |\bruin_normalize:n| is responsible for splitting an entry of the
% form |A-B| (|A| and |B| will actually be something like |1.2|) into
% the two components, which are passed to |\bruin_normalizei:nn|
\NewDocumentCommand\bruin_normalize:n {>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}m}{
  \bruin_normalizei:nn #1
}
% If the entry was |A-B|, |\bruin_normalizei:nn| is passed |{A}{B}|,
% otherwise it is passed |{A}{\NoValue}|
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_normalizei:nn {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\bruin_three:n {#1}} % simple entry
    {\bruin_three:nn {#1}{#2}} % complex entry
}
% |\bruin_three:n| splits an argument of the form |1.2.3| into the
% components; it's quite similar to |\bruin_normalize:n|
\NewDocumentCommand\bruin_three:n {>{\SplitArgument{2}{.}}m}{
  \bruin_threedo:nnn #1
  \tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_final_tl {\l_bruin_temp_tl}
}
% |\bruin_threedo:nnn| sets |\l_bruin_final_tl| to the components but
% with three digits; |1| is transformed into |001| and |1.2| becomes
% |001.002|, while |1.2.3| becomes |001.002.003|
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_threedo:nnn {
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_temp_tl
          {\bruin_threedig:n{#1}}}
       {\tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_temp_tl
          {\bruin_threedig:n{#1}.\bruin_threedig:n{#2}}}
    }
    {\tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_temp_tl
       {\bruin_threedig:n{#1}.\bruin_threedig:n{#2}.\bruin_threedig:n{#3}}
    }
}
% we do similarly for |\bruin_three:nn|, calling |\bruin_threedo:nnn| twice.
\NewDocumentCommand\bruin_three:nn
  {>{\SplitArgument{2}{.}}m >{\SplitArgument{2}{.}}m}
  { \bruin_threedo:nnn #1
    \tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_final_tl {\l_bruin_temp_tl }
    \bruin_threedo:nnn #2
    \tl_set:Nx \l_bruin_final_tl {\l_bruin_final_tl -- \l_bruin_temp_tl}
  }

\cs_new:Nn \bruin_do: {
  \cs_set:Nx \bruin_next: {
    \exp_not:N \index 
      {\l_bruin_argi_tl ! \l_bruin_final_tl \c_space_tl @ \l_bruin_argii_tl }
  }
  \bruin_next: 
}
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_threedig:n {
  \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {100}
    { 0 \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {10} {0}{} }
    {} #1
}

% |\bruin_defcite:nn| defines |#1| as a macro with one argument, first
% storing its second argument in it. So
%
% |\defcite{\citeT}{Title}|
%
% defines |\citeT| as if it were
%
% |\def\citeT#1{\emph{Title}\space\bruin_dolist:nn{Title}{#1}\l_bruin_argx_tl}|
%
% The token list |\l_bruin_argx_tl| will be built by |\bruin_dolist:nn|
\cs_new:Nn \bruin_defcite:nn {
  \cs_new:Npn #1##1{\emph{#2}\space\bruin_dolist:nn {#2}{##1} \l_bruin_argx_tl }}
\cs_set_eq:NN \defcite \bruin_defcite:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defcite{\citeherm}{Shepherd of Hermas}
\defcite{\citeash}{Testament of Asher}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

%\tracingmacros=1
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.1-2}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.2,13.9}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.3-13.4}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.10}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.11}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.20}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeherm{12.21}
\newpage


bla bla bla \citeash{1.2.3}
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeash{2.1}.
\newpage
bla bla bla \citeash{10.1,1.1,2.9-19}.
\newpage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Whoah, this is awesome. Just, ranges don't appear to work. For example "“bla bla bla” \citeherm{12.1-2}" gives an error "! Missing = inserted for \ifnum."

Comment: @TomdeBruin You're right; I've edited the answer

Comment: Is there any way to expand this to accept the following \citeherm{12.1, 35.4, 28.2}?

Comment: @TomdeBruin See edited answer

Comment: Firstly, thanks so much for the help! This is really amazing. Sorry to keep at this, but I found another issue. Sometimes you need to cite a range that spans chapters, e.g. \citeherm{1.2-3.4}... Is it possible to support his also?

Comment: Once again, thanks for the help. As I kept adding and working, I noticed one more thing. Some documents don't have chapters :D For example, I need to cite "Plea for the Christians 26". Unfortunately \citeherm{26} gives an error... Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @TomdeBruin Is that the end? :)

Comment: @TomdeBruin I've added a new implementation that should be even more robust.

Comment: Ah, I went on holiday, I doubt it is the end :D
Should I use the 'Latex 3' implementation?

Comment: I just noticed a slight error in the latex 3 implementation.
      \cs_new:Npn #1##1{\emph{#2},\space\bruin_dolist:nn {#2}{##1} \bruin_argx: }}
should read
      \cs_new:Npn #1##1{\emph{#2}\space\bruin_dolist:nn {#2}{##1} \bruin_argx: }}. (There is an extra ',' in there).

Comment: @TomdeBruin It's very "experimental". I'll try to rework it.

Comment: I tried it on the my thesis, and didn't note any problems. So it seems to work fine. I'll keep noting issues if I run into them.

Comment: (Returning to work) I have noticed a feature that would be nice if possible. Some of the works have a triple numbering scheme: 3.6.2 (book.chapter.verse). Would this be very difficult to implement?

Comment: @TomdeBruin Maybe the last? :) This has also book.chapter.verse. You owe me a beer.

Comment: I need some more help now! Suddenly (with texLive 2012) this (Latex3 version) is no longer working... I don't know why, I get the following error:
    Undefined control sequence. <argument> \l_bruin_argx_tl ,\c_space_tl \NoValue

Comment: @TomdeBruin There have been some changes in the LaTeX3 kernel. I'll try finding a workaround. In the meantime you should continue to use TeX Live 2011.

Comment: yeah, I will. I just kinda need the newest Biblatex...

Comment: @TomdeBruin The new version should work also with TeX Live 2012.

Comment: Whoops.... Done now.